# Complementary role on <aside> element for screen readers

Tags: screen-readers

I have an  element on a webpage and when using VoiceOver it says "You are currently on complementary" ... I would like the screen reader NOT to read that.
Is it possible to 'remove' the element's complementary role somehow, so that screen readers won't read it aloud?
Thank you

html aside element example:
 [element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNpg8.png)

VoiceOver reads:
[VoiceOver ➡️](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOiEl.png)